# materialize css get conflicted for select

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, materialize

I'm using cordova to develop app. In that I have used jquery mobile css and js and also I am using materialize css and js. Now I am facing problem after I included the materialize css and js file. I have used `select` to select the values. But the drop down is not displayed. But when I remove the materialize css file the drop down appears. How can I fix the problem without removing any of the file.

```
<select>
    <option> test </option>
    <option> test1 </option>
    <option> test2 </option>
</select>
```

I tried with just a normal select example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Supply some sample code, otherwise we can just guess what is wrong with your code.

Comment: No code, no debugging, sharon. It's that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materialize css file sets `select{ display: none }`  because it uses its own jQuery plugin for `<select>` tags (see http://materializecss.com/forms.html).

So, you either need to use the jQuery plugin provided by Materialize or override the

`select{ display: none }` yourself.

Comment: Yeah! Actually I removed the css for select from materialize and I tested it. My code is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Worked here but be sure that you overide css instructions :

```
select{ display: none !important}
```

Not very clean in my opinion, but works. I will prolly use another editor instead.